# Excel VSTO: keeping a custom ribbon displayed when switching workbooks

Tags: excel, vsto, ribbon, fluent

I have a Vsto Excel workbook (created in Visual Studio) which also contains a custom ribbon. If I load this workbook in Excel (2007), the ribbon is only displayed as long as my workbook has focus. It disappears if I switch to a different workbook. I understand this is by design, but is there any way of changing this behavior so that I can use the ribbon's buttons when any workbook is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have an Excel-wide ribbon, you need to create an "Excel 2007 Add-in" in VS instead of an "Excel 2007 Template" or "Excel 2007 Workbook".